# What is the correct way to get the path to an image when mapped from mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

So basically I'm mapping a div element and I'm trying to set its background image and get the background image URL from my database, but it only works with external URLS.
I've tested the path and it works well in the stylesheet.

```
{
                item.map((obj, i) => (
                    <div  style={{backgroundImage:`url(${obj.src})`}}   className='pItem' key={i}> </div>
                   
                ))
}
```

Data looks like this

```
"_id": "5ef4b10b39273719f4da3b15",
"src": "./portItem/images/starwarsMock.png",
"__v": 0
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Are there any errors in your browser console? When you say “it works well in CSS”, do you mean from a stylesheet? (Remember, `url()`s are relative to the path of the CSS, not the document.)

Comment: @Ry- the rendered HTML looks like this [image](https://imgur.com/f1XGoO3) the one with no background is the one I used the local path to my image that is inside the project folder, I get no errors in the console and yes I've tried setting the background in the css stylesheet copied the path in the database but the image doesn't show up when done like this, but works fine with external urls.

Comment: Rendered HTML as in the HTML produced by React. Or I guess DOM if this client-side.

Comment: I found a fix  ``style={{backgroundImage:`url(http://localhost:3000/images/${obj.src}.png)`}}  `` moved the image to the public folder idk if its the correct way but hey it works for now